# Need help how to parse properly

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I'm a newbie learning how to do XML parsing and received a homework parsing an XML file using Java.

This is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<deliveries>
    <van id="VID-12345">
        <package>
            <product taxable="true" productName="Headphones" isbn="123456" unitPrice="10.00" quantity="1"/>
            <product taxable="false" productName="Milk" isbn="234567" unitPrice="2.00" quantity="2"/>
            <customer lastName="Adams" firstName="Maurice" streetAddress="123 4th St" zipCode="13126" accountNumber="ACCT-54321"/>
        </package>
        <package>
            <product taxable="true" productName="Snickers" isbn="345678" unitPrice="1.00" quantity="1"/>
            <product taxable="false" productName="Milk" isbn="234567" unitPrice="2.00" quantity="1"/>
            <customer lastName="Baxter" firstName="Robert" streetAddress="234 5th St" zipCode="13126" accountNumber="ACCT-65432"/>
        </package>
    </van>
    <cart id="VID-23456">
        <package>
            <product taxable="true" productName="Snickers" isbn="345678" unitPrice="1.00" quantity="1"/>
            <customer lastName="Charles" firstName="Steven" streetAddress="345 6th St" zipCode="13126" accountNumber="ACCT-76543"/>
        </package>
    </cart>
</deliveries>
```

I need to parse it to look like this:

```
Van (VID-12345)
    Customers
        Adams, Maurice at 123 4th St, 13126
        Baxter, Robert at 234 5th St, 13126
    Total
        $17.00
Cart (VID-23456)
    Customers
        Charles, Steven at 345 6th St, 13126
    Total
        $1.00
```

How do I parse it to look like the suggested format? I've read many tutorials and examples but I could not find one that can help me. My best guess from what I've read is that it has something to do with making a list or creating objects to parse. I also can't figure out how to calculate the 'Total' (which is the sum of unitPrice * quantity of all items in each 'Package'). A solution would be nice but a detailed hint (or a relevant tutorial link) would also be helpful to guide me. I would greatly appreciate any help. This is the code I'm currently working on:

```
public class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("---=== Report ===---");
    }
    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("---=== End of Report ===---");
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("van")) {
            System.out.println("Van (" + attributes.getValue("id") + ")");
        }
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("customer")) {
            System.out.println("    Customer");
            System.out.println("        " + attributes.getValue("lastName") + ", " + attributes.getValue("firstName") + " at " + attributes.getValue("streetAddress") + ", " + attributes.getValue("zipCode"));
        }
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("cart")) {
            System.out.println("Cart (" + attributes.getValue("id") + ")");
        }
        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("product")) {
            double sum = Double.parseDouble(attributes.getValue("unitPrice")) * Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("quantity"));
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

The result (which is incorrect):

```
---=== Report ===---
Van (VID-12345)
10.0
4.0
    Customer
        Adams, Maurice at 123 4th St, 13126
1.0
2.0
    Customer
        Baxter, Robert at 234 5th St, 13126
Cart (VID-23456)
1.0
    Customer
        Charles, Steven at 345 6th St, 13126
---=== End of Report ===---
```

Edit: I've found a way that prints out the exact format I wanted, but I still don't think it's the best way and I would love to know a better way to do it.

```
public class MyHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private boolean bCustomer = false;
    private double total = 0;
    private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        System.out.println("---=== Report ===---");
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        printTotal();
        System.out.println("---=== End of Report ===---");
    }

    private void printTotal() {
        System.out.println("    Total");
        System.out.println("        $" + df.format(total));
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("cart")) {
            if (total != 0) {
                printTotal();
                total = 0;
            }
            System.out.println("Cart (" + attributes.getValue("id") + ")");
            System.out.println("    Customer");
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("drone")) {
            if (total != 0) {
                printTotal();
                total = 0;
            }
            System.out.println("Drone (" + attributes.getValue("id") + ")");
            System.out.println("    Customer");
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("scooter")) {
            if (total != 0) {
                printTotal();
                total = 0;
            }
            System.out.println("Scooter (" + attributes.getValue("id") + ")");
            System.out.println("    Customer");
        } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("van")) {
            if (total != 0) {
                printTotal();
                total = 0;
            }
            System.out.println("Van (" + attributes.getValue("id") + ")");
            System.out.println("    Customer");
        }

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("product")) {
            boolean bTax = Boolean.parseBoolean(attributes.getValue("taxable"));
            double unitPrice = Double.parseDouble(attributes.getValue("unitPrice"));
            int quantity = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("quantity"));
            if (bTax) {
                Taxable taxable = new Taxable(attributes.getValue("productName"), attributes.getValue("isbn"), unitPrice, quantity);
                total = total + taxable.getPrice();
            } else {
                NonTaxable nonTaxable = new NonTaxable(attributes.getValue("productName"), attributes.getValue("isbn"), unitPrice, quantity);
                total = total + nonTaxable.getPrice();
            }
        }

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("customer")) {
            if (!bCustomer) {
                bCustomer = true;
            }
            System.out.println("        " + attributes.getValue("lastName") + ", " + attributes.getValue("firstName") + " at " + attributes.getValue("streetAddress") + ", " + attributes.getValue("zipCode"));
        }
    }
}
```

[This](https://mega.nz/#!6u4AwSAL!A9rbw9vQleD7khC3WIbXRPMX3dauNCtB_XXlBjByiqE) is the link to my full source code that also have the objects required by the XML file that I decided not to add since it would make my post too long and painful to read. I appreciate any help!

Comment: It looks like you are close to get desired output. I think it would be good to create separated classes fore each object (Van, Customer, Cart, etc.) with required variables (firstname, lastname, address, etc.) and after you have parsed and initialized required objects (Deliveries would contain List<Van> and List<Cart>) make a method which outputs the report in required format. (not the simplest/smallest way but definitely in OOP principles)

Comment: I already have all the classes as you said but since it would make my post super long, I decided not to include them (but I can if you feel necessary). Can you explain a little bit further about initializing the objects to parse and make a method that output the report in a specific format? Thanks.

Comment: I might be talking gibberish cause it's 6am here and I had no sleep, but since you have the classes and the `startElement` method looks like it is able to get specific values, then instead of printing them to the Sys.out try to initialize the objects. After call the method which outputs the report. The objects you need to initialize should probably be an instance or class variables. Probably one thing that is needed in `startElement` to initialize the objects is an ability to distinguish if it is currently reading the package for van or cart. Sry if this doesn't help, will try after sleep.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is gibberish, cya in few hours.

Comment: This is the link to my full source code if you care to look at, and I really appreciate your help: https://mega.nz/#!Kn4gkAIZ!v-MWl24oAu-bAENzqlqcbBT3UmjhyS9Hfy1WFkLI7qk

Comment: You're making your life more complex than it should be by trying to parse and generate output at the same time. Instead, parse the XML to a Java object structure (Vans and Carts containing a list of Packages, containing a list of Products and a Customer). This can be done by XML to object mapping libraries like JAXB. Then do whatever needs to be done with these objects (by looping on the lists contained in these objects and computing the sum you need)

Comment: @JBNizet can you please give me some more detailed explanation? I'm sorry, I'm still pretty new to this parsing stuff... Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google for JAXB tutorials and read.

Comment: Does your assigned homework prescribe any particular technology for doing this? Most seasoned XML practitioners would use XSLT. Especially with recent versions of XSLT it will often only be 20% as much code as in Java.

Comment: @MichaelKay no it doesn't but I don't think he would give an assignment that requires the use of anything outside of XML.

Comment: Well, it needs something outside of XML, whether it's Java, XSLT, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import org.dom4j.DocumentException;
    import org.dom4j.DocumentHelper;
    import org.dom4j.Element;

    import java.util.List;

/**
 * @Author: panlf
 * @Date: 2019/9/16 9:27
 */
public class Dom4jTeset {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException {
        Element root = DocumentHelper.parseText(XML).getRootElement();
        List<Element> all = root.elements();
        for (Element child : all) {
            System.out.println(child.getQName().getName()+" ("+ child.attribute("id").getValue()+")");
            System.out.println("    Customer");
            double sum=0;
            for (Element pack : child.elements()) {
                Element customer = pack.elements("customer").get(0);
                for (Element prod : pack.elements()) {
                    if(prod.getQName().getName().equals("customer"))continue;
                    String unitPrice = prod.attribute("unitPrice").getValue();
                    sum+=Double.parseDouble(prod.attribute("unitPrice").getValue())* Integer.parseInt(prod.attribute("quantity").getValue());
                }
                System.out.println("        "+ customer.attribute("lastName").getValue()+", "+ customer.attribute("firstName").getValue()+ " at " + customer.attribute("streetAddress").getValue()+" "+ customer.attribute("zipCode").getValue());
            }
            System.out.println("    Total");
            System.out.println("        $"+sum);
        }
    }




    private static String XML="<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n" +
            "<deliveries>\n" +
            "    <van id=\"VID-12345\">\n" +
            "        <package>\n" +
            "            <product taxable=\"true\" productName=\"Headphones\" isbn=\"123456\" unitPrice=\"10.00\" quantity=\"1\"/>\n" +
            "            <product taxable=\"false\" productName=\"Milk\" isbn=\"234567\" unitPrice=\"2.00\" quantity=\"2\"/>\n" +
            "            <customer lastName=\"Adams\" firstName=\"Maurice\" streetAddress=\"123 4th St\" zipCode=\"13126\" accountNumber=\"ACCT-54321\"/>\n" +
            "        </package>\n" +
            "        <package>\n" +
            "            <product taxable=\"true\" productName=\"Snickers\" isbn=\"345678\" unitPrice=\"1.00\" quantity=\"1\"/>\n" +
            "            <product taxable=\"false\" productName=\"Milk\" isbn=\"234567\" unitPrice=\"2.00\" quantity=\"1\"/>\n" +
            "            <customer lastName=\"Baxter\" firstName=\"Robert\" streetAddress=\"234 5th St\" zipCode=\"13126\" accountNumber=\"ACCT-65432\"/>\n" +
            "        </package>\n" +
            "    </van>\n" +
            "    <cart id=\"VID-23456\">\n" +
            "        <package>\n" +
            "            <product taxable=\"true\" productName=\"Snickers\" isbn=\"345678\" unitPrice=\"1.00\" quantity=\"1\"/>\n" +
            "            <customer lastName=\"Charles\" firstName=\"Steven\" streetAddress=\"345 6th St\" zipCode=\"13126\" accountNumber=\"ACCT-76543\"/>\n" +
            "        </package>\n" +
            "    </cart>\n" +
            "</deliveries>";
}
```

Comment: this use Dom4j Jar

Comment: Care to elaborate? Thanks.